# Go to an image after clicking on a link using Flask

Tags: python, html, image, flask

[image: Image after using]

I am trying to make the webpage in a way that I can access some images, which are saved in the 'static/images' folder, via a hyperlink embedded under their respective names. I tried embedding a link in a page like this but the webpage had a very small icon that didn't show the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <body>
        <a href="/goto/Koala.png"> go </a>
     </body>
</html>
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,  session, redirect, request, url_for
import pandas as pd
import os

IMG_FOLDER = os.path.join('static', 'images')
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['IMG_FOLDER'] = IMG_FOLDER

@app.route('/',methods=["GET"])  
def homePage():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/goto/<name>')
def show_index(name):
    file = name
    full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['IMG_FOLDER'], file)
    return render_template("goto.html", user_image = full_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <img src="{{ user_image }}" alt="User Image">
</body>
</html>
```

On the contrary, when I am using this in the following way it shows up fine -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,  session, redirect, request, url_for
import pandas as pd
import os

IMG_FOLDER = os.path.join('static', 'images')
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['IMG_FOLDER'] = IMG_FOLDER

@app.route('/',methods=["GET"])  
def homePage():
    return "hello"

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/goto')
def show_index():
    file = 'Koala.png'
    full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['IMG_FOLDER'], file)
    return render_template("goto.html", user_image = full_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I may be doing something wrong somewhere. Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to embed these names in the form of for loop in a data-frame. Anyway, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['IMG_FOLDER'], file)` will return `static\images\file`. However, what you need is: `\static\images\file`. Therefore, what you need to run is:

`full_filename = "\\" + os.path.join(app.config['IMG_FOLDER'], file)`.

Alternatively, if you want to display the image and have a link to goto, you could do the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="/goto/{{user_image.split('\\')[3]}}">
            <img src="{{user_image}}" alt="User Image">
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for showing me this! Thanks, Jakob!